Linear fit parameter errors of NOAA CO2 measurements
I'm trying to plot data from NOAA regarding CO2 concentrations. In particular I'm asked to first plot the fit and then print the fit parameters and reduced chi square along with their uncertainties using a linear fit. The plots come out as I expected but there are errors that crop up that I can't seem to fix. These errors show up when calculating the parameters and their uncertainties, as well as the reduced chi square. It all shows up as infinity. I know the errors are due to dividing by zero but that's a result of certain measurements in the data having an uncertainty of zero so I can't do much about that.
Link to dataset: https://gml.noaa.gov/ccgg/trends/ though mine only goes up to September 2023
Any uncertainty that is negative is changed to an uncertainty of 0.1
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos, sqrt, exp, sin, pi, array
from matplotlib import cm
data=np.loadtxt('co2_data.txt', skiprows=2)
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def linfit(x, p0, p1):
    return (p0*x)+p1
def quadfit(x, p0, p1, p2):
    return p0*(x**2)+(p1*x)+p2

x=data[:,2]
t=array([i-x[0] for i in x])
y=data[:,3]
yerr=data[:,7]
for i in range(len(yerr)):
    if yerr[i]<0:
       yerr[i]=.1
guesses = (1.5, 310)
(p0, p1), cc = curve_fit(linfit, t, y, p0 = guesses, sigma = yerr)
(up0, up1) = np.sqrt(np.diag(cc))
print(f'p0 = {p0:.4} +/- {up0:.4f} ppm/year')
print(f'p1 = {p1:.4f} +/- {up1:.4f} ppm')
xm = np.linspace(t[0], t[-1], 201)
ym1 = linfit(xm, p0, p1)
yfit1=linfit(t, p0, p1)
n = len(t)
p=2
rcsq = sum(((y - yfit1)/yerr)**2)/(n-p)
print(f'Reduced chisquared for linear fit = {rcsq:.5f}')

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:968: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  transform = 1.0 / sigma
<ipython-input-44-c1614db438c8>:9: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  (p0, p1), cc = curve_fit(linfit, t, y, p0 = guesses, sigma = yerr)
<ipython-input-44-c1614db438c8>:18: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  rcsq = sum(((y - yfit1)/yerr)**2)/(n-p)
p0 = 1.5 +/- inf ppm/year
p1 = 310.0000 +/- inf ppm
Reduced chisquared for linear fit = inf

The only thing I could think to do was change my guesses for the fit but considering that a linear fit is pretty bad to begin with, I don't think it's possible to fix the errors. But I also don't want to rule out that the errors are simply errors and can't be fixed. Are the errors a feature of this fit or a code/fit error?

Lets import the dataset:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

data = np.loadtxt("https://gml.noaa.gov/webdata/ccgg/trends/co2/co2_mm_mlo.txt")

t = data[:, 2]
x = data[:, 3]
s = data[:, -1]

Then we shift time to origin and impute missing uncertainty:
t -= t[0]
s[s <= 0.] = 0.1

Now you can fit and compute your quantities without any problem:
def model1(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

def model2(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x ** 2 + b * x + c

popt1, pcov1 = optimize.curve_fit(model1, t, x, sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True)
popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(model2, t, x, sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True)

xhat1 = model1(t, *popt1)
xhat2 = model2(t, *popt2)

chi21 = np.sum(((x - xhat1) / s) ** 2) / (t.shape[0] - len(popt1))
chi22 = np.sum(((x - xhat2) / s) ** 2) / (t.shape[0] - len(popt2))

Graphically it leads to:


I'm a bit confused. From what I can tell is that you turned all the zero uncertainties into .1 in addition to all the negatives. But why change those zeros?

You are right, you can indeed change this behaviour. The key point is zero uncertainties are not normal data (probably due to rounding effect, or even worse constant series during a whole month). You must change it as it prevent you to fit and compute chi square. A simple trick is to replace those zero value by a small value such as 1e-6 or whatever. In this snippet I chose to impute missing and non valid uncertainties with the same place holder, but you are free to impute zero values with another placeholder.
